# Solving colissions in simple TypeScript Game Engine

Tags: javascript, typescript, collision-detection, game-physics, game-engine

I am currently creating a simple Game Engine/Framework in TypeScript. So far everything works, I have even implemented multiplayer, but this is the point where my Colission detections breaks. In short: the player who joined earlier will be able to push the player who joined later around but not vice verca. The desired behaviour is that both players simply stop when colliding.

The Engine has a `update()` function which gets called at every tick. This functio then goes over an array of GameObjects and calls their respective update function.I have not implemented proper physics, I rather just move the player X and Y position like this.

`this.transform.position().y += Player.speed * deltaTime();`

After the position update is done I resolve any colissions like this:

```
this.collidesWith(GameObject, (collider: GameObject) => {
    let distances = {
        left: (this.transform.position().x) - (collider.transform.position().x + collider.getSize().width) ,
        top: (this.transform.position().y) - (collider.transform.position().y + collider.getSize().height),
        right: (this.transform.position().x + this.getSize().width) - (collider.transform.position().x),
        bottom: (this.transform.position().y + this.getSize().height) - (collider.transform.position().y),
    }
    let abs = {
        left: Math.abs(distances.left),
        top: Math.abs(distances.top),
        right: Math.abs(distances.right),
        bottom: Math.abs(distances.bottom),
    }

    let dir = Math.min(abs.left,  abs.top,  abs.right, abs.bottom);

    if(dir == abs.left){
        collider.transform.updateX(distances.left);
    }
    if(dir == abs.top){
        collider.transform.updateY(distances.top);
    }
    if(dir == abs.right){
        collider.transform.updateX(distances.right);
    }
    if(dir == abs.bottom){
        collider.transform.updateY(distances.bottom);
    }
})
```

But the problem is that the Object who Spawns first (in my case the player who connects first) will be able to push around the player who joins later, since it gets resolved first. I have already tried to not move them directly but rather calculate everything first and then resolve it, but the problem still persists.

I know why my code has this problem, but im really unsure what would be the best way to resolve it. As said before I just want a player to stop as soon as he moves into another player.

Answer (score 0):

By doing this:

```
foreach player:
    move
    collide with other players
```

Instead of:

```
foreach player:
    move

foreach player:
    collide with other players
```

Then the first player will move, get pushed by the other players then the second player will do the same.

So if a player moves into another player it stops moving and then the other players do the same thing: move into player stop moving (get pushed back). This  way, no player will have priority over one another.